# Círculo com Porcentagem Efeito jQuery

Tags: jquery

Encontrei aqui no site um tópico sobre determinado efeito. É um de porcentagem em um círculo.

Não consegui encontrar um site de exemplo. Mas é mais ou menos assim:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Porém, o preenchimento de cor no círculo é feito em *runtime*.
Alguém se lembra de algum plugin que faz isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara de uma olhada nesse plugin https://github.com/Shopify/dashing. Acho que ele poderá te ajudar no que deseja, a demo do que ele é capaz de fazer esta aqui http://dashingdemo.herokuapp.com/sample

Comment: Obrigado, Rafael. Mas ele é totalmente customizável ? Achei muito grosso o Donut.

Comment: Acho que para questão de customização esse aqui http://www.jqueryrain.com/?T5za65Di deve ser mais interessante para você.

Comment: Cara, gostei mais desse. Já vi que é bem personalizável. Obrigado. Negada que fechar meu tópico...